# Return datatable/column values from two data table comparison

Tags: c#

My Datatable 1 (dtOutput) Format `(termid,faultid,faultdesc,faulttime,devicetype)`

My Datatable 2 (dtOpenEvent) Format `(termid,faultid)`

I want to retrieve those values which are present in Datatable 2 but not in Datatable 1...based on two columns `(termid,faultid)` no table have primary keys.

I Searched on net and find code which return diff between two data table...

**Now how can i retrieve column values from it ? either in another data table or in string variable**

Code :-

```
DataTable dtOpenEvent;
dtOpenEvent = Generix.getOpenEvents(ref Connection);
DataTable dtOutput;
dtOutput = Generix.getFeedData(ref Connection);
var matched = from table1 in dtOpenEvent.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in dtOutput.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<string>("ATM") equals table2.Field<string>("termid")
              where table1.Field<int>("Event") == table2.Field<int>("faultid") 
              select table1;
var missing = from table1 in dtOpenEvent.AsEnumerable()
              where !matched.Contains(table1)
              select table1;
```

Comment: why did not you try the simplest way if you have been stuck. Simplest way mean two loops first on table2.. to compare its two fields with table1's each row if any row found similar, continue to next value of table2. if not matched with any row of table1 till last row.. then add this row of table1 to 3rd table

Comment: :) Yup off course. I be glad if you get helped.

Comment: I have done. You can check. Hope it will meet what you want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove all of the columns in dt1 and then do except.

like this:
`var diff =dt2.AsEnumerable().Except(dt1.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);`

full example:

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            dt1.Columns.Add("termid", typeof(Int32));
            dt1.Columns.Add("faultid", typeof(Int32));
            dt1.Columns.Add("faultdesc");
            dt2.Columns.Add("termid", typeof(Int32));
            dt2.Columns.Add("faultid", typeof(Int32));

            dt1.Rows.Add(1,2,"desc");
            dt1.Rows.Add(3, 4, "desc");
            dt1.Rows.Add(5, 6, "desc");
            dt2.Rows.Add(1, 2);
            dt2.Rows.Add(3, 4);
            dt2.Rows.Add(7, 8);

            dt1.Columns.Remove("faultdesc");
            var diff =dt2.AsEnumerable().Except(dt1.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);

            foreach (var row in diff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row["termid"] + " " + row["faultid"]); //prints 7 8
            }
```

or instead of removing columns you can select them through linq or dataview like this:

```
        var view = new DataView(dt1);
        DataTable dt3 = view.ToTable(true, "termid", "faultid");
```

modified example:

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            dt1.Columns.Add("termid", typeof(Int32));
            dt1.Columns.Add("faultid", typeof(Int32));
            dt1.Columns.Add("faultdesc");
            dt2.Columns.Add("termid", typeof(Int32));
            dt2.Columns.Add("faultid", typeof(Int32));

            dt1.Rows.Add(1,2,"desc");
            dt1.Rows.Add(3, 4, "desc");
            dt1.Rows.Add(5, 6, "desc");
            dt2.Rows.Add(1, 2);
            dt2.Rows.Add(3, 4);
            dt2.Rows.Add(7, 8);

            var view = new DataView(dt1);
            DataTable dt3 = view.ToTable(true, "termid", "faultid");
            var diff =dt2.AsEnumerable().Except(dt3.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);

            foreach (var row in diff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row["termid"] + " " + row["faultid"]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
As you said : I want to retrieve those values which are present in Datatable 2
but not in Datatable 1...based on two columns `(termid,faultid)`
```

*Translation* according to the context of question : You have two tables `dtOutput` and `dtOpenEvent`. You want to get values of `dtOutput` in a third table such that no row of third table has same value with first two cells of any row of `dtOpenEvent`. Then here it is

```
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add("termid");
dt3.Columns.Add("faultid");
int nr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dtOutput.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < dtOpenEvent.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dtOutput.Rows[i][0] == dtOpenEvent.Rows[j][0] 
            && dtOutput.Rows[i][1] == dtOpenEvent.Rows[j][1])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        dt3.Rows.Add(dt3.NewRow());
        dt3.Rows[nr][0] = dtOutput.Rows[i][0];
        dt3.Rows[nr][1] = dtOutput.Rows[i][1];
        nr++;
    }
}
```